# Xml Document Save call doesn't expire cache dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working with some codes where I am trying to modify an XML file by loading in XmlDocument and then adding/removing an element. This file has a cache dependency set which triggers a piece of code when ever we change the file. If I edit the file in editor or use FileStream it does expire the cache and trigger codes but not with XmlDocument.Save method. Any idea what could be the reason behind this?

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ssl.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);
XmlElement ele = doc.CreateElement("directory");
XmlAttribute atr = doc.CreateAttribute("path");
atr.Value = "/";
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//SecurePages");
node.AppendChild(ele);
doc.Save(filePath);
```

Above code does modify the file but it doesn't expire the cache item which it should since file is modified. The cache does expire if change the file manually or using FileStream.

**UPDATE**
I found a workaround which is if I load the XmlDocument using LoadXml method then Save call does trigger the cache dependency. I am still not sure why Load/Save combination doesn't work

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ssl.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(ReadTextFile(filePath));
XmlElement ele = doc.CreateElement("directory");
XmlAttribute atr = doc.CreateAttribute("path");
atr.Value = "/";
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//SecurePages");
node.AppendChild(ele);
doc.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: The problem is that  you did not show us your code that saves the document.

Comment: I am sorry. Let me update the post but its just save call with file path.

Comment: But that's different from `Save(FileStream)`. Try creating your `FileStream` in the way that works, then passing the `FileStream` to `Save`.

Comment: just updated the post with code.

Comment: Ok, so assuming that what worked before was `FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath);`, then try passing that to `Save`: `doc.Save(stream);`

Comment: I am trying to find why its not working with save. It should work since file contents are changed.